# If $X > Y$, what can we say about $X^2$ and $Y^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $X > Y$, is the following analysis correct for the squares?

- If both $X$ & $Y$ are positive, then $X^2 > Y^2$ for all $X$ and $Y$
- If both $X$ & $Y$ are negative, then $X^2 < Y^2$ for all $X$ and $Y$
- If one of them is positive and the other negative, then any one of the below can be true: $X^2 > Y^2$, or $X^2 = Y^2$, or $X^2 < Y^2$.

Comment: Looks good to me, but I wouldn't call it linear algebra because you're squaring things.

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Comment: Michael: What will u call it?

Comment: @MichaelBurr What is wrong with squaring things in Linear Algebra? I wouldn't call it Linear Algebra because you are trying to assign a total ordering to matrices.

Comment: The question, as posed, doesn't involve matrices; it's a question about squaring numbers.  Since the squaring operation is not a linear map, it seems to strange to call this a linear algebra question (perhaps is comes from a question in linear algebra).  I would just call it a question about inequalities.

Comment: Indeed (linear-algebra) is misleading. Assuming X and Y are real numbers, this should be tagged (real-analysis).

Answer (score 3):

The statements are correct - not sure if you are required to also actually *prove* them. If so, you may want to note that $X^2-Y^2=(X+Y)(X-Y)$, where we know that $X-Y$ is positive, hence all depends on whether $X+Y$ is positive, negative, or zero.